# How to run Octave scripts from bash?

Tags: bash, octave

```
pavel@pavel-VirtualBox:~/projects/csv_converted$ sh plot.sh 
plot.sh: 2: plot.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected


pavel@pavel-VirtualBox:~/projects/csv_converted$ ./plot.sh 
'usr/bin/octave-cli: invalid option -- '


pavel@pavel-VirtualBox:~/projects/csv_converted$ cat plot.sh 
#!/usr/bin/octave -qf
E=csvread("a.csv");
S=csvread("b.csv");
plot(S(:,1),S(:,2),";line1;",E(:,1),E(:,2),";line2;");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Using Octave version 3.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Got this!
Need to run as:

```
octave plot.sh
```

and add in last line `pause(10);` to keep plot on screen during some time (not exit immediately)